# A Div with a floating Div inside, won't fit to the content

Tags: html

```
<div style="background-color:black">
   <div style="float:right">
       Test message
   </div>
<div>
```

This will show 'Test message' with white background because the parent div didn't fit the content.

How can make the div fit to the content? (without using table, or display:table since it's not supported in IE)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
<div style="background-color:black; overflow: auto;">
   <div style="float:right">
       Test message
   </div>
<div>
```

It's a cleaner way to do the clearfix :)

Answer (score 2):

A common solution is to put a `<br style="clear: both;">` *after* the floating element to clear the float and cause the parent element to wrap the elements.

```
<div style="background-color:black">
   <div style="float:right">
       Test message
   </div>
   <br style="clear: both;">
<div>
```

Apart from the problem, I'd suggest to put the styles in a separate CSS file, if not realised yet.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this is the old *clearfix* issue. This is almost a total necessity when using css and floats for layouts. See http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html for a brief description and fix. Or for a more in depth look, see here http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html